# Cannot share header files with another project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I wanted to have one project which would contain common header files that could be used by other projects in the same solution (Unfortunately I cannot accomplish this task). In order to accomplish this task here is what I tried

1-Created a new C++ console application called common.

2-From the properties of this project I changed the configuration type to static Library.

3-I added a simple header file `commonheader.h` to the project having a class `person` and built it as a result I got

```
C:\Users\Raj\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Ctest\Debug\Common.lib
```

4-Now in order to use that header file from a different project I created another project
called  Test. And in the properties of test I added `Common` as  a reference

5-I then tried to access the person class however the VS2010 still complains that it cannot find the person class.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ? . I added the path 
`C:\Users\Raj\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Ctest\Debug\` in addition include addition files of the `Test` project. Any ideas  how I can access the person class

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the .lib files only contains the compiled source of your implementations, you still need to include the header files themselves to get access to the interface

Comment: Any suggestions on how I do that ?

Comment: The header file in the common project is called `commonheader.h`. I tried adding this header but VS2010 states cannot find the header file

Comment: Are you sure you have the path to commonheader.h added in the include path of your second project?